# DetailsView: Index was out of range

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, detailsview

I'm trying to get the datakey value from `DetailsView` and paste it in a form. I've included all the datakeynames but still couldn't get the value to paste it in my formview but I've encountered this probles:

> Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

I've tried `SelectedValue` and SelectedRow but it only retrieve the primary keys.

Attached here is my code-behind. Help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
    {
        TextBox bookid = FormView1.FindControl("bookidTextBox") as TextBox;
        bookid.Text = DetailsView1.DataKey[1].ToString();

        TextBox employee = FormView1.FindControl("EmployeeID") as TextBox;
        employee.Text = DetailsView1.DataKey[2].ToString();
    }
}
```

Heres the code from the control

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            DataKeyNames="reservationid,bookid,EmployeeID,reservedate" DataSourceID="booklendingDataSource" Height="50px" 
            Width="300px" >
            <Fields>

                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="Lend" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="reservationid, bookid, EmployeeID" HeaderText="reservationid" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="reservationid" 
                    Visible="false" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="bookid" HeaderText="bookid" 
                    Visible="false" SortExpression="bookid" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="booktitle" HeaderText="Title" 
                    SortExpression="booktitle" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Emp PIN" 
                    SortExpression="EmployeeID" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="reservedate" HeaderText="Reserve date" 
                    SortExpression="reservedate" />

                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="isdeleted" HeaderText="Deleted" 
                    SortExpression="isdeleted" />

            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
...

<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="lenid" 
            DataSourceID="lendformDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert" OnDataBound="FormView1_DataBound" >
            <EditItemTemplate>

        ...

            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                bookid:
                <asp:TextBox ID="bookidTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("bookid") %>' />
                <br />
                EmployeeID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="EmployeeIDTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeID") %>' />
                <br />
                department:
                <asp:TextBox ID="departmentTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("department") %>' />
                <br />
                dateborrowed:
                <asp:TextBox ID="dateborrowedTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("dateborrowed") %>' />
                <br />
                expdateofreturn:
                <asp:TextBox ID="expdateofreturnTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("expdateofreturn") %>' />
                <br />

                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Where exactly have you got the exception ??

Comment: on which row is the exception thrown? I mean, the indexes begin from zero, so you may not have index two...

Comment: I've edited my post please take a look. I just want to get the datakey value 'bookid', 'EmployeeID' and 'reservedate' and paste it in a FormView.

Comment: I have edit my answer after editing your question. just try you will see the magic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an better way to access the values of `DataItem`

```
bookid.Text = ((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["bookid"].ToString();
employee.Text = ((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem)["EmployeeID"].ToString();
```

Comment: Got an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
I'll try to fix it as usual.

Comment: Place a null check. It is never a good idea to call ToString on a retrieved value directly.. It can be null as well..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your DetailsView1.DataKey[1] not starts at [0]?

Comment: Yes because I only need the other data inside not the primary key. In my table i have a primary key,a bookid, an employeeid so I want to get the bookid and employeeid.

Comment: @Loupi; you have two Data Keys ? Can you show your source Where you mentioned ?

Comment: I've edited my post. Please have a look. I need to retrieve the three datakey value 'bookid', 'EmployeeID' and 'reservedate'